# Stanford NLP - identifying the respective Intents

Tags: c#, machine-learning, text, stanford-nlp

In Stanford NLP there is Named Entity Recognizer feature to identify the entities from the conversation. Is there a way to configure Utterances that can be trained to point to a particular intent? Something similar to LUIS (Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the C# port of this, SharpNLP.  There are no "Intent" classes in that system, but you could experiment with creating your own Intents and correlate these intents by looking at the nouns, verbs, etc. in POS tagging steps.

You may want to also add your own named-entity parsing, if you're in a particular environment for which the Stanford NLP models don't recognize.